# Mutability Function Output

Tags: ocaml, record, mutable

```
type dot = {mutable x:int; mutable y:int} 

let f (dot1:dot) (dot2:dot) : int = 

dot1.x <- 12;
dot2.x <- 26;
dot1.x
```

I'm not sure what this would evaluate to. I assume it would evaluate to 12 always but the answer key says that it only evaluates to 12 "sometimes". I guess this has to do with whether or not dot1 and dot2 are aliases but I still don't understand why this would matter considering we are only modifying dot1 and accessing the x field of dot1.

Comment: "*considering we are only modifying dot1*" - but you are also modifying `dot2` in the line `dot2.x <- 26`, and if they both refer to the same object then the result would be 26. Have you tried running it?

Comment: I have not tried running it. But I think I get it now. In the case where `let dot2 : dot = dot1`, would `dot1` and `dot2` be referentially equal or structurally or both? I get confused with that.

Comment: `dot1` and  `dot2` would be different names, or *bindings*, for the same mutable object. So `dot1` and `dot2` are referentially equal, which *implies* they are structurally equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, when the returned value would be `26` not `12`:

```
# let p = {x=0; y=0};;
val p : dot = {x = 0; y = 0}

# f p p;;
- : int = 26
```

Here `p` is an object that has two mutable fields `x` and `y`. When applied, function `f` gets the same object as `dot1` and `dot2`, so, both names `dot1` and `dot2` refer to the same object and, no matter which name you're using, it will lead to the modification of the `p` object.

Another example, that doesn't involve any functions, but just `let` bound names,

```
# let p1 = p;;
val p1 : dot = {x = 26; y = 0}
# let p2 = p;;
val p2 : dot = {x = 26; y = 0}
# p1.y <- 1;;
- : unit = ()
# p;;
- : dot = {x = 26; y = 1}
# p2.x <- 11;;
- : unit = ()
# p;;
- : dot = {x = 11; y = 1
```

As you can see name binding is just a name biding, so it is not creating a new object or anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
let dot = {x=0; y=0;};;
f dot dot;;
```